# Cannot find module 'jasmine-reporters'

Tags: node.js, protractor, jasmine-reporters

My 'npm' folder is in D:\Box folder because I don't have space on C.
I configure Protractor to work by adding in *System Environment Variables* new environment variable named PROTRACTOR with value: . 
Then in System Path I've entered: %PROTRACTOR%\bin

And this works for Protractor perfectly.

Now I want to add jasmine-reporters and I paste in npm\node_modules\jasmine-node\node_modules 'jasmine-reporters' and 'jasmine-growl-reporter' folders.
Then run one test with jasmine report in conf.js and I see error message:

> Cannot find module 'jasmine-reporters'.

What I try:

1. Paste 'jasmine-reporters' and 'jasmine-growl-reporter' folders in npm\node_modules
2. Add in System Environment Variables NODE_PATH: D:\Box\npm\node_modules

The result is the same.
Someone, please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your global node_modules on the D:\ drive you need to change prefix in npm config as described in [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#prefix-configuration)

Short version (in command prompt as administrator):

`npm config set prefix d:\box`

To see what is the current path you can issue:

`npm config get prefix`

Comment: Hi I change the prefix and now the path is D:\Box\npm but I still see the same error

Comment: Did you reinstall jasmine-reporters? By changing your global prefix, you effectively uninstalled previously installed global packages.

Comment: I just install it: D:\Box\npm>npm install jasmine-reporters@^1.00
jasmine-reporters@1.0.2 node_modules\jasmine-reporters
└── mkdirp@0.3.5   And try again but the result is the same...

Comment: Can you update your question with your protractor config?

Comment: Actually I resolve my problem by increase the C disk space and move everything there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
-Remove jasmine-reporters

Go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
-Remove npm-Cache

Reinstall jasmine-reporter and npm